Finding the SUM while using PREVIOUS in Report Viewer
The customer wants to have a daily report of changes in their system.  Without going into much detail about the project, I'll just show what I'm trying to do.  Unfortunately, I have little experience with Report Viewer.
| Column A | Fields!VALUE.Value  | DIFF NEW-PREVIOUS | 
|          |                     | Expression Below  | 
| -------- | ------------------- | ----------------- |
|     1    |            1        |          0        |
|     2    |            10       |          9        |
|     3    |            12       |          2        |
|     4    |            18       |          6        |
|     5    |            20       |          2        |
|     6    |            1        |          -19      | 
|     7    |            9        |          8        |

                             **SUM |          8        |**

I am able to use the PREVIOUS function to collect the data
= IIf(Previous(Fields!VALUE.Value) <> 0,IIf(Fields!VALUE.Value <> 0, Fields!VALUE.Value - Previous(Fields!VALUE.Value), 0),0)

But I am unable to find figure out how to get the SUM.
I can do the math in Excel as shown in the attached screen capture, but the customer wants to automate it and shown in a report form.
I tried using the SUM with the function on the final row
=Sum(Fields!VALUE.Value - Previous(Fields!VALUE.Value))

then I was trying to figure out if I can use the expression as a variable.  I was unsuccessful.
It is probably something easy, but as someone who is not familiar with the software, it has been difficult to solve.
